# After upgrade from 9.1 to 9.3, commands still point to 9.1

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Upgraded from 9.1 to 9.3 on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. Everything worked great but running commands like 'createdb' still runs them from the 9.1 path.

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/createdb: unrecognized option....
```

Edit, additional info:
I used this gist https://gist.github.com/ibussieres/11262268
I already uninstalled 9.1 with the regular 'sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.1'

This is the output of requested commands

```
which createdb
  /usr/bin/createdb

createdb --version
  createdb (PostgreSQL) 9.1.14

which psql
  /usr/bin/psql

psql --version
  psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1: remove createdb for 9.1

When in doubt, use `dpkg -S` to learn which packages provide a certain command.

Example:

```
$ dpkg -S createdb 
postgresql-doc-9.1: /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.1/html/tutorial-createdb.html 
postgresql-doc-9.1: /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.1/html/app-createdb.html 
postgresql-client-9.1: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/createdb
postgresql-client-common: /usr/bin/createdb 
postgresql-doc-9.1: /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.1/html/manage-ag-createdb.html 
postgresql-client-9.1: /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/man/man1/createdb.1.gz 
wwwconfig-common: /usr/share/wwwconfig-common/pgsql-createdb.sh
```

From this it appears that `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/createdb` is provided by `postgresql-client-9.1`, and that it's still installed. You may uninstall it since presumably you have now `postgresql-client-9.3`

### Option 2: address the right instance without removing anything

Debian allows multiple simultaneous PostgreSQL instances, which is why it allows to have different `createdb` at the same time. Assuming you'd need to keep `postgresql-client-9.1`, that is possible too.

The `/usr/bin/createdb` command, in the standard `$PATH` (as opposed to deep under /usr/lib), is actually a wrapper that will call the real binary for the correct version depending on the context.

That context may be given through the additional option, specific to Debian/Ubuntu, called `--cluster` to specify which version and server it should target. It's also available as an environment variable `PGCLUSTER`, as documented in [pg_wrapper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html), and defaults can also be specified in `/etc/postgresql-common/user_clusters`.

### Weird: createdb pointing to 9.1.14 and psql to 9.3.5

The one thing that doesn't look right in your question is this issue.
Normally `pgsql` and `createdb` should reach the same version/cluster, since in fact they should point to the same script to start with:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/createdb /usr/bin/psql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 sept.  8  2012 /usr/bin/createdb -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 sept.  8  2012 /usr/bin/psql -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

This would require further digging into the environment to find out how your situation differs from the default.